# Footer sitting too far up page

Tags: css, positioning, footer

My footer sits where I want it to when there is enough content above it to 'push' it to the bottom of the page (http://v3.edharrisondesign.com/), but without content it sits too far up (http://v3.edharrisondesign.com/about/).

Any ideas why?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it at all. If you want there to be some space between the top and footer, however, do what John_C suggested and give your content div (the div which would house the about content) a `min-height`. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with the footer not being at the bottom of the screen, and unless you want the footer to be stuck constantly, in view, at the bottom of the screen you will need JavaScript to calculate and position the footer for you (seeing as each user will have a different height body element etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search google for sticky footer you'll find that this is a common problem with a few solutions. Anyway, I took a look at your site and here's what you need to do:

1) to the `html's` ruleset, add this:

```
height: 100%;
```

2) `body`'s ruleset:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 80px; /* same as footer's height */
```

3) `footer`:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; /* you already have this */
```

This solution takes advantage of the box-sizing property. If supporting older browsers is a requirement, it won't work - you'll need an extra element in the html for that (let me know if this is what you want).

***Great looking site, btw!***

Comment: Thanks John! I've never used this method before, be good to give it a go (Im not worrying about older browsers for this). And thanks for the kind words - its people like you who are making it possible for me to build the site!

Answer (score 0):

## thumbnail-container{min-height:400px}

will work in ie7/8/9 and the other main browsers. IE6 will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What John's saying is that there needs to be a container between your header and footer, with a minimum height so that you give the browser a set amount of pixels you would like between the two, no matter what. For the homepage, it is "thumbnail-continer", but on your internal page it looks like you dont have any content well at all. Either way (whether you place the thumbnail container in the internal page or create a new div altogther), create a content well on each page and give it the minimum height you would like it.

Comment: Thats a really great explanation Nick. Obviously Im going to add a div with content, but I was just thinking I may have been going about adding my footer the wrong way (since it was sitting too high). Anyway turns out its all okay, just need to remember to add a min height to any content that doesn't push the footer down far enough.